# C++ - Pass member functions of any class to another class

Tags: c++, member-functions

I am in the process of writing a template class that would implement a Listener interface for every component that would need it within my application. I want a component to be able to listen to changes to an individual field within a listened object. The fields of each object are represented by an enum, and I've got a simple Notifier/Publisher that works great as such:

```
template <typename EFieldsEnum>
class AbstractNotifier
{
public:
    void addListener(EFieldsEnum listenedField, INotifierListener<EFieldsEnum>* listener)
    {
        if (_listeners.find(listenedField) == _listeners.cend())
        {
            std::unordered_set<INotifierListener<EFieldsEnum>*> listeners;
            listeners.insert(listener);
            _listeners.emplace(listenedField, listeners);
        }
        else
        {
            _listeners.find(listenedField)->second.insert(listener);
        }
    }

    void notify(EFieldsEnum updatedField)
    {
        for (INotifierListener<EFieldsEnum>* listener : _listeners[updatedField])
        {
            listener->onUpdate(updatedField);
        }
    }

protected:
    std::unordered_map<EFieldsEnum, std::unordered_set<INotifierListener<EFieldsEnum>*>> _listeners;
};
```

I am trying to change the method signature slightly, in order for each listening component to register by passing a *void()* method that would be called as a callback, rather than implement the *onUpdate* generic method followed by a switch case. Ideally, I would want my listening components (say, Component1) to register without having to define a specific Listener interface for each type of Notifier that I will have, as such :

```
notifier.addListener(FieldEnum::MyField1, this, &Component1::onMyField1Updated);
```

and then Component2 could also register as such :

```
notifier.addListener(FieldEnum::MyField1, this, &Component2::someOtherMethod);
```

without Component1 and Component2 needing to implement a common interface. Would this be possible? I am struggling to figure out what type is expected to generically represent the member method that is passed through :

```
class IListener {};

void (IListener::*ListenerCallback)();

template <typename EFieldsEnum>
class AbstractNotifier
{
public:
    void addListener(EFieldsEnum listenedField, IListener* listener, ListenerCallback listenerCallback)
    {
        std::pair<IListener*, ListenerCallback> pairToAdd = std::make_pair<IListener*, ListenerCallback>(listener, ListenerCallback);
        if (_listeners.find(listenedField) == _listeners.cend())
        {
            std::unordered_set<std::pair<IListener*, ListenerCallback>> listenersAndCallbacks;
            listenersAndCallbacks.insert(pairToAdd);
            _listeners.emplace(listenedField, listenersAndCallbacks);
        }
        else
        {
            _listeners.find(listenedField)->second.insert(pairToAdd);
        }
    }

    void notify(EFieldsEnum updatedField)
    {
        for (const std::pair<IListener*, ListenerCallback>& listenerAndCallback : _listeners[updatedField])
        {
            IListener* listener = listenerAndCallback.first;
            ListenerCallback listenerCallback = listenerAndCallback.second;
            listener->*listenerCallback();
        }
    }

protected:
    std::unordered_map<EFieldsEnum, std::unordered_set<std::pair<IListener*, ListenerCallback>>> _listeners;
};
```

Comment: Perhaps `std::function<void()>` could be of use?

Comment: you do not need to call `find` when inserting a new element to a `unordered_map` (and certainly not twice). `insert` returns an iterator and a `bool`. The `bool` tells you if the insertion took place (if not the element was present before) and the iterator is to the element in the map

Comment: sorry misread, but the same holds for `emplace`

Comment: `addListener` can be `_listeners[listenedField].insert(pairToAdd)`

Comment: `if (_listeners.find(listenedField) == _listeners.cend())` -- If you got doing this from writing Java code, I suggest you not use Java as a model in writing C++ code.  As mentioned, there is no need to use `find()` to insert an element.  Using another language as a model in writing C++ code will lead to 1) Buggy programs, 2) Inefficient programs, and 3) Programs that will look weird to a C++ programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::function<void()>`

Here's a somewhat simplified version of your `AbstractNotifier` that will accept callbacks from any class (or no class at all):

```
template <typename EFieldsEnum>
class AbstractNotifier
{
public:
    void addListener(EFieldsEnum listenedField, std::function<void()> listenerCallback)
    {
        listeners_[listenedField].push_back(listenerCallback);
    }
    
    // Helper method template to wrap member function pointers
    template <typename Listener>
    void addListener(EFieldsEnum listenedField, Listener* listener, void(Listener::*listenerCallback)())
    {
        addListener(listenedField, [=]() { (listener->*listenerCallback)(); });
    }
    
    void notify(EFieldsEnum updatedField)
    {
        for (auto& callback : listeners_[updatedField])
        {
            callback();
        }
    }

protected:
    std::unordered_map<EFieldsEnum, std::vector<std::function<void()>>> listeners_;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1eed2062bebfbac3)

Note that I gave up the "uniqueness" constraint that your current implementation has and used a `std::vector`.  This is because it's difficult to impossible to really compare `std::function`s, and it's easy to have very different looking `std::function`s that end up calling back to the same underlying code.

i.e. All three of the following end up calling the same member function, but hold totally different types and can't be easily compared:

```
// Different lambdas, so different types
std::function<void()> f1([&someObject]() { someFunc.foo(); });
std::function<void()> f2([&someObject]() { someFunc.foo(); });
std::function<void()> f3(std::bind(&SomeType::foo, someObject));
```

Comment: anyhow when I register a listener twice I'd expect to be called back twice rather than only once

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much for this detailed answer!
Using a vector is not too much of a problem, I can understand why comparing the equality of lambda functions can be tricky if not impossible